# How to move django models from one app to another

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So we have a django backend already in production with a reasonable amount of data.During the initial stages, we had a small team of two and we were also working with deadlines. I would also admit we were beginners and didn't follow best practices.Because of this,all our models were defined in one app.Now the project is messy and I also learnt it is not a good practice to have many models in one app.Now my question is,how can we move some of this models to new different apps in our project without running into migration issues or worse loosing the data? Our models also have a lot of relationships.Just for reference,we are using postgres databases.

I have reasearched the internet for solution but haven't found a comprehensive approach to doing it.Most of the answers here also seems outdated.Some people also recommend to use south which is deprecated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've got the feeling django-import-export package (https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might come in handy here. Without the necessary details about your project, I can tell you what I would do in this situation: I would rebuild my Django project in parallel. I mean to start over with the appropriate architecture, make the necessary adjustments in the entire codebase, and then bring my data in. Test it all out and only then redeploy. It might be laborious, but I guess it is far less risky.  It all depends on how far you've got with your current codebase.